# (python)What are the 2 argumets in os.kill?

Tags: python-3.x, arguments, typeerror

when I use os.kill(), this happends.

```
import os
os.kill()
TypeError: kill() takes exactly 2 arguments (0 given)
```

what are the 2 argumets?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[os.kill()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html?highlight=os.kill#os.kill)

> os.kill(pid, sig): 
>   Send signal sig to the process pid. Constants for the specific signals available on the host platform are defined in the signal module.

- PID is the process ID you want to kill
- sig is the signal to send, per the signals module